# Consuming Rest api with array list of xml response using spring java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to consume REST API which gives me XML response.I'm mapping XML response to POJO file.While the outer most XML element is mapped properly,the inner nested array element is returning null values. Following are the request response and other code files :

XML Response:

```
<ArrayOfRouteListItem
    xmlns="http://some url..."
    xmlns:i="http://url...">
    <RouteListItem>
        <ArrivalCountry>(Saronic Islands, Greece)</ArrivalCountry>
        <ArrivalPort>Agistri</ArrivalPort>
        <DepartCountry>(Saronic Islands, Greece)</DepartCountry>
        <DepartPort>Aegina</DepartPort>
        <HeaderKey>HA</HeaderKey>
        <ReturnFlag>R</ReturnFlag>
    </RouteListItem>
    <RouteListItem>
        <ArrivalCountry>(Saronic Islands, Greece)</ArrivalCountry>
        <ArrivalPort>Aegina</ArrivalPort>
        <DepartCountry>(Greece)</DepartCountry>
        <DepartPort>Piraeus</DepartPort>
        <HeaderKey/>
        <ReturnFlag>R</ReturnFlag>
    </RouteListItem>
</ArrayOfRouteListItem>
```

POJO class  ArrayofRouteListItem.java :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)    
@XmlRootElement(name="ArrayOfRouteListItem" , namespace="http://some url ...")
public class ArrayOfRouteListItem {     
@XmlElement(name = "RouteListItem")     
public List<RouteListItem> routeItem = new ArrayList<RouteListItem>();
}
```

POJO Class RouteListItem.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="RouteListItem")   
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)       
@XmlType(namespace="http://some url ..")
    public class RouteListItem implements Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name="ArrivalCountry")
    public String arrivalCountry;

    @XmlElement(name="ArrivalPort")
    public String arrivalPort;

    @XmlElement(name="DepartCountry")
    public String departCountry;

    @XmlElement(name="DepartPort")
    public String departPort;

    @XmlElement(name="HeaderKey")
    public String headerKey;

    @XmlElement(name="ReturnFlag")
    public String returnFlag;
    ......

}
```

MY Main Application (Controller.java):

```
   public class Controller {

    private static DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        demoGetRESTAPI();

    }
    public static void demoGetRESTAPI() throws Exception 
    {
        try
        {
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://www.url...");
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/xml");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 200) 
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : " + statusCode);
            }
            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            String apiOutput = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            System.out.println("xml file content : " + apiOutput); 

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ArrayOfRouteListItem.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(apiOutput);
            System.out.println("reader object :  " + reader.toString());
            ArrayOfRouteListItem routeList = (ArrayOfRouteListItem) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(routeList, System.out);

            System.out.println("size: " + routeList.getRouteItem().size() + "  .get(0)    :     " + routeList.getRouteItem().get(0).getArrivalCountry());
          }
        finally
        {
            //Important: Close the connect
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }
```

The Output which I'm getting are :

```
reader object :  java.io.StringReader@38c5cc4c
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:ArrayOfRouteListItem   xmlns:ns2="http://some url...">
<RouteListItem/>
<RouteListItem/>
<RouteListItem/>
<RouteListItem/>
<RouteListItem/>
<RouteListItem/>
</ns2:ArrayOfRouteListItem>
routeList.size: 6    routeList.getRouteItem().get(0).getArrivalCountry() : null
```

Comment: it may be getArrivalCountry() is null please check all data

Comment: I checked all the fields all are coming null,this is just as an example, as you can see the whole object is coming null in output

Comment: Please see answer @naresh

Answer (score 0):

Complete Working example, Please see this:
User.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String profession;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String profession) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
}
```

UserDao.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class UserDao {

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> userList = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("Users.dat");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                User user = new User(1, "Mahesh", "Teacher");
                userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                userList.add(user);
                saveUserList(userList);
            } else {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userList;
    }

    private void saveUserList(List<User> userList) {
        try {
            File file = new File("Users.dat");
            FileOutputStream fos;

            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(userList);
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

UserList.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author CE
 */
@XmlRootElement(name="users")
public class UserList {
    @XmlElement(name="user")
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {

    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

WSCLiente .java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
public class WSCLiente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sURL = new StringBuilder(100);
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            sURL.append("http://localhost:2016/Simpleweb/rest/UserService/users");
            InputStream is = new URL(sURL.toString()).openStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            int cp;
            while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
                sb1.append((char) cp);
            }
        } catch (Exception me) {
            System.out.println("## Exception :" + me.getMessage());
        }
        String apiOutput = sb1.toString();
        System.out.println("xml file content : " + apiOutput);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserList.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(apiOutput);
        UserList uu= (UserList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        for (int i=0; i<uu.users.size();i++) {
            User u = uu.users.get(i);
            System.out.println("Yes:"+u.getProfession());
        }
    }

}
```